# Cannot install Windows 7 in native Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

I'm not able to install Windows 7 from a bootable USB in a Windows 10 native machine I recently acquired. I tried all the alternatives I guess to prepare the USB, disabling Secure boot, using GPT/MBR partition, NTFS/Fat32, changing to legacy mode in BIOS, and still I'm not able. Sometimes I receive "Windows failed to start 0xc000000d", others it directly does not recognize the USB...

Last try I configured bootable USB using GPT partition scheme, UEFI (non CSM) target system, Large Fat32 file system. BIOS set to UEFI boot. The next error appears when I start from USB:

"Windows failed to start...
...

- File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
- Status: 0xc000000d
- Info: an error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.
  "

I'm using RUFUS to prepare the bootable USB. BIOS information:

- American Megatrends
- 5.011
- UEFI 2.4; PI 1.3
- VB2 003S x64
- 07/02/2020

I don't know what can I do more. Anybody can show me the right way?

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: Based on your BIOS version the used PC is nearly brand new. Windows 7 on new PCs is not supported. Nearly all Intel/AMD CPUs released 2017 and later are AFAIK no longer supported on Windows 7. Also the other hardware components like chipsets are not supported. If you want to run an ancient/historical Windows version use hardware of the same age or use a virtual machine.

Comment: But what is exactly the restrictive element? I mean, it is a Intel i5-5257u from 2015. It's a small factor computer I bought, and yes, it's new, but now with the top components of the market.

Comment: As a comment, Windows 10 bootable USB works in this machine. Windows 7 does not.

Comment: This has been asked here many times, Windows 7 will not install on newer hardware for many reasons, bios, chipset, processor, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you plugging the USB stick into a USB3 port?  If so, try using a USB2 port.  Windows 7 didn't natively have USB3 drivers.

Comment: It's a USB2 port. I guess it has to be an issue of computer's age, that is recently acquired. But I cannot manage what is the problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try another USB stick.
I had a similar issue. The system where I prepared the stick doesn't show any issue with the stick.
Nevertheless the target system could not boot from it, no matter which method I tried.
After endless tries another stick did the job for me.

Comment: I tried with 3 different sticks. Same issue. I don't think this will be the problem

Comment: Found German discussion were a guy could solve the issue by following this English guide (Rufus/diskpart based):
https://www.eightforums.com/threads/uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-in-windows.15458/

Comment: I already did that. Didn't work for me